# SQL*Loader error when executing from shell script

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Getting error

> LRM-00116: syntax error at ')' following ')'

while executing the below SQL*Loader statement from shell script. However, if I execute the same single statement as command line argument, then it is working fine.

Can you please help to understand this error?

```
sqlldr USR/PWD@HOST control=<(echo "LOAD DATA INFILE input.csv BADFILE input.csv_bad DISCARDFILE input.csv_dsc INSERT INTO table TEMP_INPUT_TBL FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS (CBPID,SAM_KEY,HHID)")
```

Comment: I think it related to escape character.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you do it that way? Normally, you'd create a control file (let's call it `load.ctl`) and use it while running SQL*Loader, e.g.

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE input.csv 
BADFILE input.csv_bad 
DISCARDFILE input.csv_dsc 

INSERT INTO table TEMP_INPUT_TBL 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(CBPID,SAM_KEY,HHID)
```

and then

```
sqlldr USR/PWD@HOST control=load.ctl
```